# How can I attach lodge pole rails to 5" wooden fence posts?

Tags: fence, carpentry, pole

We want to build a lodge pole fence. Each pole is 5" x 8'. Each rail is 5" x 10'. Posts will be concreted in every 10'. One rail at the top, between posts. Second rail at bottom, 1' above ground. Posts and rails must be on same vertical plane because steel deer fence will be stapled to them.

> How can we connect the rails to the posts?

I'm thinking there must be some kind of bracket that attaches horizontal 5" pole to vertical 5" pole.

Horizontal rails are each 12'2" and installer has already cemented the vertical posts into the holes. Posts spaced so that rails fit between two posts.  He's planning to use brackets.

I can't find brackets online.  I don't know what they're called.

Comment: posts may need to be closer that 10 ft

Comment: A few pictures are always a great help in answering these questions.

Comment: jsotola:  Why closer than 10'?

Answer (score 1):

It's been done with pole barn nails for centuries. Won't that work for you? Just drill the rails for two toenails each (from above and below) at about 30 degrees from horizontal. No need for fancy, expensive hardware.

I suggest 6" ring-shank nails and a nice big hammer. A heavy punch or set will let you finish them off snugly without beating up your rails.

I'd consider setting your posts at about 9 foot intervals and lapping the top rails with half-notches. Might look more polished and would make for easier nailing.

Comment: Thanks, isherwood.  I will suggest to installer.  Might save me $$.   Plus his crew time is $45/hr/man.   Welcome to California

Comment: ... the state where folks ask questions on a DIY site and then pay others do DI? :P